# Infinite loop won't break even when correct input is given

Tags: python, if-statement, user-input, infinite-loop

I want to give the user a choice to "Do something". They have to input either "yes" or "no" to break out of the loop. Then user input ("ui") is stored in "user_input" and used in an if statement to "Do something".
I tried the following code but no matter what I input, the loop won't break.

```
user_input = ""
while True:
    try:
        ui = input("Do something? (yes/no): ").lower()
        if ui != "yes" or ui != "no":
            raise Exception
            
    except Exception:
        print(f"Error: {ui} is not a choice")
    
    else:
        print("Found no Errors")
        user_input = ui
        break
        
if user_input == "yes":
        print("Did somethin")
elif user_input == "no":
        print("Did nothing")
```

Comment: `ui != "yes" or ui != "no"` is always true

Comment: Every conceivable value of `ui` is either unequal to "yes", or unequal to "no".  You want an `and` instead of an `or` there.

Comment: ui != „yes“ or ui != „no“ ist always true. Use and except of or

Comment: use `if ui != "yes" and ui != "no":` (i.e. and rather than or).

Comment: or `ui not in ('yes', 'no')`

Comment: Thanks, i didnt realize.

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep it simple. You can modify this one to make it more simpler.

```
user_input = ""
answer = False #assign bool variable to test the condition

#loop while the condition is true
while answer != True:
    try:
        ui = input("Do something? (yes/no): ").lower()
        
        if ui == 'yes' or ui == 'no':
            print("Found no Errors")
            user_input = ui
            if ui == "yes":
                print("Did something")
            else:
                print("Did nothing")
            
            answer == True #condition becomes false
            #break the loop
            break
        #raise exception if condition is false    
        else:
            raise Exception
    
    except Exception:
        print(f"Error: {ui} is not a choice")
```

Comment: Sam P, why did you add a break statement in your code? Does setting answer == True not break the loop in the next iteration?

Comment: You can remove, I was trying to provide options for using  break or changing the condition. Like I said you can modify it. Thanks for reaching out @DanielAlegriaSallo